# read UUID of partitioned Image-Disk

Tags: linux, partition

i know i can read the GUID of a Partition like this:

```
blkid /dev/sdx
```

Problem:

i have created a 4GB-Image

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=./myImage.img bs=1M count=4000
```

which is partitioned to 3 different sections:

> partition 1) 2GB ext4 with label rootfs
>
> partition 2) 1GB FAT32 with label boot
>
> partition 3) 1GB FAT32 with label myEtraPart

so how can i read the GUID's of those Partitions, without
mounting them on the host filesystem??

Thanks

Comment: This question is really off-topic, voting to move to [SU].

Answer (score 0):

`kpartx` should be able to help you do this. Perhaps `partprobe` can do this as well (but I've never used on anything else than blockdevices)

Comment: i have already tried  all kind of tools that i knew as: parted, kpartx, partprobe..., none of the can show the uuid of a not mounted block device... confusing :((

Comment: I meant what I said "be able to **help** you do this". Then do the usual loopmount trick with offsets from the kpartx output, see e.g. http://madduck.net/blog/2006.10.20:loop-mounting-partitions-from-a-disk-image/